# Get value from emit in input field with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component

I know this has a simple answer but I appear to be stuck. I have an upload image input in a form. Following several tutorials, I have successfully created the upload method. My issue is once the image is uploaded to Firestore storage I use `this.$emit('imgurl', downloadURL)`

My problem is I do not know how to get that value so when the user submits the form the url gets added to the database.

Parts of the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="field avatar">
    <label for="avatar">Avatar</label>
    <input type="file" name="imgurl" accept="image/*" @change="detectFiles($event.target.files)">
    <div class="progress-bar green" :style="{ width: progressUpload + '%'}">{{ progressUpload }}%</div>
    <img class="avatar" v-bind:src="this.downloadURL">
</div>
```

Methods:

```
detectFiles (fileList) {
    Array.from(Array(fileList.length).keys()).map( x => {
        this.upload(fileList[x])
    })
},
upload (file) {
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    this.uploadTask = storage.ref('avatars/'+file.name).put(file);
}
```

Watch:

```
watch: {
        uploadTask: function() {
            this.uploadTask.on('state_changed', sp => {
                this.progressUpload = Math.floor(sp.bytesTransferred / sp.totalBytes * 100)
            }, 
            null, 
            () => {
                this.uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                    this.downloadURL = downloadURL
                    this.$emit('imgurl', downloadURL)

                })
            })
        }
    }
```

Add to the database:

```
db.collection('teams').add({
    team_name: this.team_name,
    team_id: this.team_id,
    bio: this.bio,
    url: this.imgurl,
}).then(() => {
   this.$router.push({ name: 'Admin' })
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function as a prop to a child component, then call this function passing your `downloadURL` as argument.

## Parent Component

---

HTML

```
<child passURL="getDownloadURL">
```

JS

```
data: {
    return {
        downloadURL: null
    }
},
methods: {
    getDownloadURL: function(url) {
        this.downloadURL = url
    }
}
```

## Child Component

---

JS

```
props: ['passURL'],
```

Inside your watcher, you can call

```
this.passURL(downloadURL)
```

Instead of $emit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I added a hidden input field 
`<input type="hidden" name="imgurl" v-model="imgurl">`
and replaced the emit with `this.imgurl = downloadURL`

Comment: How are you getting the `imgurl` from your child component? You can do this in a Vue way.